# org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl not found

Tags: spring, https, spring-security

I get the following warning in my spring security-context.xml when I try to use ssl over https in tomcat.
Any reason why? Do you know how to fix it?

**Referenced bean 
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl' not found**

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Security Authentication Manager -->

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>    
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"  />

        <!-- Other interceptors -->

    </security:http>
```

Thanks